# What made Andy lose her immortality?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-old-guard

In the movie *The Old Guard*, Andy/Andromache loses her invulnerability. What triggers this? Is it when they reach a certain age, or is it because Nile joined the immortal group?

Comment: It seemed to be also be a power that could be blocked by the "mental" state. Like, losing faith (her deeds seemed ineffective, etc.), that would prevent it without her realizing it. A little like "positivity" seems to "help" in curing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## It is not explained.

As far as I know, it doesn't happen in the original comics. In the [movie](https://theoldguard.fandom.com/wiki/The_Old_Guard_(2020_film)), it just eventually happens, seemingly without a specific cause.

> The group discloses that they are not actually immortal: their power to heal eventually stops without warning.